# Is NaH2PO4 and Na2HPO4 buffer a neutral buffer?

Tags: ph

My teacher mentioned in class that a mixture of two salts derived from polybasic acid functions as a buffer solution. But is it a neutral buffer or acidic buffer?

Comment: You ask whats the pH of this buffer?

Comment: No. But what type of buffer it is?....yeah in one way pH may be.

Comment: What type of buffer? There's no such classification I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that dissolving equal proportions of the dibasic and monobasic sodium phosphate salts in water solution yields a buffer that is very close to pH 7 - for all practical purposes, neutral pH.